# Placing \section inside makebox

Tags: sectioning

I would like to have an image on the same line as my section header.  This is the code

```
 \makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
\section{Header}
\hfill
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{somefigure}}%
    \hfill
}
```

If I just write some text rather than `\section{}` it works fine, but I'm apparently not allowed to call `\section` within a `\makebox`. I get the error
"Package titlesec error: Entered in horizontal mode". Any way around this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\section` cannot be put into a horizontal box. Quick and dirty/untested: \section[Header]{Header\hfill\includegraphics[...]{...}}. The internal `\@startsection` sets the section title in the standard classes. It could be modified to add the graphics. Or a package as `titlesec` might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, the `\includegraphics` can be directly put into the section title. However the title is reused in other places such as the table of contents. Therefore the optional argument is used without the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section[Hello World]{Hello World\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=4em]{tiger}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]